# Pandoc document conversion failed when trying to add selectInput() to flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

Im trying to add a simple `selectInput()` to my flexdashboard but I get:

````
File shared/selectize/css/selectize.bootstrap3.css not found in resource path
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99
Execution halted

---
title: "My Dashboard"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---
  
### Chart 1

```{r}
library(readr)
library(haven)
library(shiny)

subs<-structure(list(Sold_Pr = c(6500, 173000, 60000, 73000, 155000, 
105000, 140000, 39900, 73500, 46000, 99900, 180000, 164000, 120000, 
206000, 160000, 67400, 215000, 145000, 175000, 350000, 425000, 
435000, 490000, 545000, 585000), Area = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("411", "415", "981", 
"8001", "8002", "8003", "8004", "8005", "8006", "8007", "8008", 
"8009", "8010", "8011", "8012", "8013", "8014", "8015", "8016", 
"8017", "8018", "8019", "8020", "8021", "8022", "8023", "8024", 
"8025", "8026", "8027", "8028", "8029", "8030", "8031", "8034", 
"8035", "8037", "8038", "8039", "8040", "8041", "8042", "8043", 
"8044", "8045", "8046", "8047", "8048", "8049", "8050", "8051", 
"8052", "8053", "8055", "8056", "8057", "8058", "8059", "8060", 
"8061", "8062", "8063", "8064", "8065", "8066", "8067", "8068", 
"8069", "8070", "8071", "8072", "8073", "8074", "8075", "8076", 
"8077"), class = "factor"), Closed_Date = structure(c(18668, 
18933, 18716, 18740, 18639, 18845, 18708, 18676, 18733, 18695, 
18715, 18709, 18794, 18803, 18750, 18787, 18906, 18810, 18855, 
18870, 18626, 18786, 18808, 18864, 18961, 18914), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-26L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

selectInput("ar", label = "Select Area:",
            choices =unique(subs$Area), selected = unique(subs$Area)[1])

```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what's the reason for this issue. Probably related to ongoing efforts to support more recent versions of Bootstrap. Anyway you could make you code work by specifying the bootstrap version you want to use in the YAML like so (also see this [vignette](https://rstudio.github.io/flexdashboard/articles/theme.html#bootswatch-themes-1)):

Note: I also had to specify the bootswatch theme to get the default flexdashboard look.

````
---
title: "My Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme:
      version: 3
      bootswatch: cosmo
---
  
### Chart 1

```{r}
library(readr)
library(haven)
library(shiny)

subs <- structure(list(Sold_Pr = c(
  6500, 173000, 60000, 73000, 155000,
  105000, 140000, 39900, 73500, 46000, 99900, 180000, 164000, 120000,
  206000, 160000, 67400, 215000, 145000, 175000, 350000, 425000,
  435000, 490000, 545000, 585000
), Area = structure(c(
  1L, 1L, 1L,
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
  1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c(
  "411", "415", "981",
  "8001", "8002", "8003", "8004", "8005", "8006", "8007", "8008",
  "8009", "8010", "8011", "8012", "8013", "8014", "8015", "8016",
  "8017", "8018", "8019", "8020", "8021", "8022", "8023", "8024",
  "8025", "8026", "8027", "8028", "8029", "8030", "8031", "8034",
  "8035", "8037", "8038", "8039", "8040", "8041", "8042", "8043",
  "8044", "8045", "8046", "8047", "8048", "8049", "8050", "8051",
  "8052", "8053", "8055", "8056", "8057", "8058", "8059", "8060",
  "8061", "8062", "8063", "8064", "8065", "8066", "8067", "8068",
  "8069", "8070", "8071", "8072", "8073", "8074", "8075", "8076",
  "8077"
), class = "factor"), Closed_Date = structure(c(
  18668,
  18933, 18716, 18740, 18639, 18845, 18708, 18676, 18733, 18695,
  18715, 18709, 18794, 18803, 18750, 18787, 18906, 18810, 18855,
  18870, 18626, 18786, 18808, 18864, 18961, 18914
), class = "Date")), row.names = c(
  NA,
  -26L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```                                                          
                                                                  
```{r, eval=TRUE}
selectInput("ar",
  label = "Select Area:",
  choices = unique(subs$Area), selected = unique(subs$Area)[1]
)
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was just having the same issue with this exact application of shiny functions within flex dashboard, and tried adjusting the YAML, however when I tried using dateRangeInput() and dateInput() I ran into another error code 99.

It turns out that I didn't declare 'runtime: shiny' at the top (and it doesn't seem like you or the person who responded to you did either).

Doing this solved both problems I had.